# Date into SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, date, format

in the TextView I have the date formatted in "Locale" now I have to insert it into the sqlite db. How do I convert the format suitable for SQLite?
This is my Content Values

```
cv.put(MyTable.DATE, mDate.getText().toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can insert it as a `long`:

```
cv.put(MyTable.DATA, mDate.getTime());
```

Then retrieve it as a `long` and use the following constructor:

```
mDate = new Date(cv.getAsLong(MyTable.DATA));
```

Additionally, if you  need to save the `Locale`, just store it separately as a String:

```
cv.put(MyTable.LOCALE, mLocale.getLanguage());
```

and get it later:

```
mLocale = new Locale(cv.getAsString(MyTable.LOCALE));
```

Comment: my date field is TEXT, so if I do not work --- 
cv.put(MyTable.DATA, mDate.getTime());

Comment: @user2856560 what is the field `MyTable.DATA`?

Comment: is the name of the table with the DATE field (in the Helper class declared as TEXT)

Comment: So for this to work, you need to change how your SQL insert handles the `ContentValues` - ie, you need to change it so that it will insert a `long` instead of a `String`.

Comment: So I have to convert the 'String' to 'long'. How?
then there will be problems with the dates entered so far?

Comment: If you do not wish to change your database structure, you can convert your `long` to `String` using `String.valueOf(long)`, and convert back using `Long.parseLong(String)`.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you store strings in text format for machine-readable code. See
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html. SimpleDateFormat allows you to go between Date and String. I've seen some documentation that suggests you should pass dates internally in binary format. I tend to disagree. Storing a date in text format (if you know the format) is simpler and safer.

Comment: I think you tried to say human-readable, not machine-readable :) I'm a fan of storing time as long so that DB can concentrate on storing data where app can choose multiple displaying format and change format later.

Comment: Sorry I have not explained very well!
I just have to convert the format "Local" my textview in the format supported by SQLite "yyyy-mm-dd" during insertion. (I use sqlite in the field 'TEXT' for dates) thanks